# get value from url than select the checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on the checkbox dynamic `url` create. If I refresh the page than checkbox show selected if brand name have some value my `javascript` code working fine.

```
Shop?brand=Emporio,Primigi%2088&category=&gender=&start=2000&end=4000
```

The problem is if brand name contain space like primigi 88, Lee Cooper than it select all the checkbox. I want to select the checkbox only that is in url.

```js
$(function() {
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {

var sPageURL =
  decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
  sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
  sParameterName,
  i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
  sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

  if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
  }
}
  };
  var brand = getUrlParameter('brand');
  if (brand) {
var brand_array = brand.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < brand_array.length; i++) {

  $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + brand_array[i] +
    ']').attr('checked', true); // this will working fine if categories name not contain any space

}
  }

  var category = getUrlParameter('category');
  if (category) {
var category_array = category.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < category_array.length; i++) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + category_array[i] +
    ']').attr('checked', true);

}
  }

  var gender = getUrlParameter('gender');
  if (gender) {
var gender_array = gender.split(",");
for (var j = 0; j < gender_array.length; j++) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + gender_array[j] +
    ']').attr('checked', true);

}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">

  <h3>Brands</h3>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="item_filter brand" value="North East">North East</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="item_filter brand" value="Emporio">Emporio</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="item_filter brand" value="Lee Cooper">Lee Cooper</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="item_filter brand" value="Primigi 88">Primigi 88</a>

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="item_filter brand" value="Us polo assn">Us polo assn</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try changing `$('input[type=checkbox][value=' + brand_array[i] + ']')` to `$('input[type=checkbox][value="' + brand_array[i] + '"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you need to wrap the value in the attribute selector in quotes so that the spaces are also included, eg:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + gender_array[j] + '"]')
```

That being said there's a few things you can do to improve your logic. Firstly, use `prop()` instead of `attr()` where possible. Secondly, you don't need the function name when declaring a function as a variable.

Lastly, you can also DRY up the logic by removing the repeated block that checks the checkboxes by building one large array of all the filters and looping through that. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var getUrlParameter = function(sParam) {
    // param retrieval logic...
  };

  var brands = (getUrlParameter('brand') || '').split(',');
  var categories = (getUrlParameter('category') || '').split(',');
  var genders = (getUrlParameter('gender') || '').split(',');
  var filters = brands.concat(categories).concat(genders);

  filters.forEach(function(filter) {
    $(`input[type="checkbox"][value="${filter}"]`).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Literally what I said. Probably should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: True, although I added a section explaining how the OP can improve the logic by DRYing it up.

Comment: Yeap fair enough. +1.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + filter + '"]').attr('checked', true); works this  thanks

Comment: If `attr()` works and `prop()` doesn't you may need to update the version of jQuery you're using. `prop()` was added in v1.6 over 7 years ago